# PHP & AJAX Delete works only with the first row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a simple PHP blog system. Under the Add Post page user can give a title and body text. The posts are on the Posts page, where the user can delete the posts.

My problem is: Only the first post can be deleted. The others not.

Here is my code for show the posts:

```
<?php
$database->query('SELECT * FROM posts');  
$rows = $database->resultSet();
?>

<div class="container">
 <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
 <h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
 <p><?php echo $row['body']; ?></p>
 <small><?php echo $row['create_date'] ?></small>
 <form method="post">
  <input  id="deleteid" type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo 
  $row['id'] ?>">
  <input id="delete_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
   name="delete" value="Delete">
 </form>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <br><br>
</div>
```

And this is my AJAX code:

```
$("#delete_button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "?action=delete",
      data: "delete_id=" + $("#deleteid").val(),
      success: function (result) {
        if (result == 1) {
          //window.location.assign("views/posts.php");
        } else {
          alert("Error");
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use same id for multiple input/div or any other HTML tags. Please change id="deleteid" to class="deleteid" and also change in your click event. So your this line will change to -

```
<input  class="deleteid" type="hidden" data-deleteid="<?php echo 
  $row['id'] ?>" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
```

And you ajax code will change to -

```
$(".delete_button").click(function () {
    var deleteid = $(this).data('deleteid');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "?action=delete",
      data: "delete_id=" + deleteid ,
      success: function (result) {
        if (result == 1) {
          //window.location.assign("views/posts.php");
        } else {
          alert("Error");
        }
      }
    });
  });
```